# Query returning unwanted values when two tables are compared

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am working on a query which compares two tables and returns one or zero rows for each type of product. It returns zero if after comparing the values of two tables and if second row has at least one better row than the first table and it returns one row if the first table has the best row.

For Example I have two tables T1 and T2 with following rows

Table T1

```
Id  Market          Term        BidCP       Bid     Offer   OfferCP
8   C1            Sep14/Oct14   Nothing     -60     NULL    NULL
1   C1            Sep14/Oct14   punt        -50     NULL    vgc
2   abc           Sep14/Oct14   disc        -390    -285    fvfvf
7   abc           Sep14/Oct14   vgc         -415    -185    vfvfv
10  abc           Sep14/Oct14   ggX         -415    NULL    Pvfv66
11  abc           Sep14/Oct14   frgth       -440    NULL    vvf
14  abc           Q4 14/Q1 15   begrt       -425    NULL    vf
6   xyz-Cushing   Sep14/Oct14   ererrrUS    -100    NULL    NULL
3   xyz-Cushing   Sep14/Oct14   gth          -75    NULL    vfv
```

Table T2

```
id      product term    bidcp        bid    offer   offercp
3546    C1     Sep14    dddddddd    -975    NULL    XoOM
3562    C1     Sep14    erft        -985    NULL    NULL
3608    C1     Sep14    BPl         NULL    NULL    jjjj
3574    C1     Oct14    NULL        NULL    -925    P6678
3603    abc    Sep14/Oct14  CVXvg   -350    -300    Shl
3621    abc    Sep14/Oct14  NULL    NULL    NULL    jnhj
```

Upon running the SQL query on the above two tables the result should be like

```
 Id   Market        Term        BidCP       Bid     Offer   OfferCP
    14  abc         Q4 14/Q1 15 begrt       -425    NULL    vf
     1  C1          Sep14/Oct14 punt        -50     NULL    vgc
```

The above results can be explained as 
For Product C1 in first table has no row with term `Sep14/Oct14` so the row with highest value of bid and then lowest value of offer is returned.
Similarly for Product abc and term  Q4 14/Q1 15. But for product abc and term `Sep14/Oct14` in the first table when compared with the second table same product and term, the second table has better values of bid and offer so, the row is not returned in the results

I am using the below query but they aren't yielding expected results

The SQL QUERY is as follows

```
    select distinct t1.market,t1.Term,
       (case when t1.Bid >= isnull(t2.bid,-99999) then t1.bid
             else NULL
        end) as bid,
       (case when t1.offer <= (isnull(t2.offer,99999)) then t1.offer
             else NULL
        end) as offer

from (SELECT Market,Term, MAX(bid) as Bid, MIN(offer) as offer FROM InferredProductBids GROUP BY Market,Term) t1 left join
     (SELECT product,Term, MAX(bid) as Bid, MIN(offer) as offer FROM CanadianCrudes GROUP BY product,Term) t2
     on t1.Term = t2.Term and t1.Market=t2.Product
```

When I tried to execute the above query I got the following error

```
Column 'InferredBids.BidCP' is invalid in the select list because 
it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

When I tried to include `BidCP` and `OfferCP` in the `Group by` clause, I got unwanted results with is obvious.

I get the accurate results when I just exclude `OfferCP` and `BidCP` from both `select` and `group by` statements but I want both `BidCP` and `OfferCP` to be included in my results.
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Remove BidCP and OfferCP from the subqueries.  I assume the combination of market,term,max(bid) ,and min(offer) make the record unique...so create a third join from t1 back to InferredBids on those 4 keys.   Repeat for CanadianCrudes

Comment: Those combinations are not unique, they may be same or different